# Is this radical edit appropriate?

Tags: discussion

I am puzzled by the following edit (#2): https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/74051/revisions

The edit changed:

```
<?php print $node->content['body']['#value'] ?>
```

into:

```
<?php print $node->field_subtitle[0]['view'] ?>
```

I am not going into a discussion about which version is the correct answer to the original question (to be honest, I don't care and I don't know).

The question asked here on meta is: Is this type of (IMHO) *radical change* of content "in spirit" with SE?  Or even appropriate?

I assume the change was made because the editor thinks the answer provided is dead wrong, and the edited version is the correct answer.  But IMHO, coding errors that are not blatant typos should *not* be corrected by radical editing. Instead, there should be a comment pointing out the error (leaving it up to the reader to make a decision about how to act on the information, and the original author to incorporate the correction in his or her answer if he or she agrees).

I humbly suggest that the editor does a rollback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No that edit was not appropriate, I've rolled it back.

Editing code for formatting reasons is ok, but changing the meaning of someone else's code is not the right thing to do, even if you think/know it's incorrect.

If the code is incorrect, the correct action to take is to leave a comment stating why, and optionally downvote the answer until it's remedied.

For reference: [How far can I refactor someone else's code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88627/how-far-can-i-refactor-someone-elses-code)

Answer (score 6):

It was my mistake: I was trying to edit the first sentence; I didn't notice I changed the code too, which is a little strange, since I didn't make any copypasta. `:)` Since I edited the answer in its grace period, it is probable the user changed his answer when I was editing it, with the result that I edited the answer keeping the old version.

Edits should not change the code shown in a post, with the exception of better formatting the code. Even in the case the code is wrong, or doesn't work, the code should not be changed.
If the code is wrong, leave a comment to the user who wrote the answer, down-vote it if it is blatantly wrong or off the tracks. If you know the answer, and you have time to write it, write a new answer.

Editing a wrong answer instead of writing your own answer is wrong. If you think the user who answered the question can edit his own answer, leave a comment. If you have something else to say, or the part of the code that is wrong is more than one line, you could consider more adding your own answer.